# Generic vs application initialization for typescript module based application

Tags: typescript

I am moving my existing JS app (shopping cart + associated website) over to Typescript.

I have a whole bunch of functions right now in my JS file to initialize different external components

```
    // Initialize components
    initBrowser();
    initKnockout();
    initModernizr();
    initjQM();
    initGoogleAnalytics();
```

They set up everything from `window.console.log` to `knockout.js` bindings, custom `Modernizr.js` tests and jQuery mobile page transition logic.

My question is how in Typescript modules should I best go about organizing and initializing things like this with modules. (My app is small and I'm using only internal modules)

#### Option 1 : Module with no 'class' that just initializes everything

```
module RR
{
     initBrowser();
     initKnockout();
     initModernizr();
     initJQM();
     initGoogleAnalytics();

     // define functions
}
```

#### Option 2 : Module with 'static initializer' class

```
module RR 
{
    class AppInitializer
    {
        private static instance:AppInitializer = new AppInitializer(); 

        constructor()
        {
           initBrowser();
           initKnockout();
           initModernizr();
           initJQM();
           initGoogleAnalytics();             
        }

        // define functions
     }
}
```

#### Option 3 : Single application object that initializes everything and is created only once

```
module RR 
{
    class MyApp
    {    
        constructor()
        {
           init();             
        }

        init()
        {
            initBrowser();
            initKnockout();
            initModernizr();
            initJQM();
            initGoogleAnalytics(); 
        }

        // define functions
     }

     // create the application
     var MyApp = new MyApp();

}
```

#### Option 4 : ...... Your idea here .....

What's a good way to initialize things like this that aren't really related to a specific application module or class.

In addition I have other init functions to set up my jQuery unobtrusive initialization, eg. my Login button, customer service page logic. These functions are specific to the actual website and different from the functions I mentioned before

```
    // initialize shopping cart
    initLogin();
    initCustomerService();
    initVideo(true);
```

Up until now I've just initialized everything all at once in a single closure, but I'd like to organize things much better going forward and would appreciate any advice.

Comment: I like your 3rd option. It seems more appropriate regardless of the size of your application. This gives you the option to add an interface in case you'd like to add unit testing / mocking.

Answer (score 2):

You can use *external modules*. `Bootstrap.ts`:

```
// Load components
import initBrowser = require('./initBrowser');
import initKnockout = require('./initKnockout');
import initModernizr = require('./initModernizr');
import initjQM = require('./initjQM');
import initGoogleAnalytics = require('./initGoogleAnalytics');

// Initialize components
initBrowser();
initKnockout();
initModernizr();
initjQM();
initGoogleAnalytics();
```

This way you do not need to worry about ordering your JavaScript files. The ordering is explicit in the way the code is written *and* you don't pollute `window` unnecessarily.

To learn more about external modules : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0&hd=1

Comment: already watched that one :-) btw you're doing a fantastic job on those videos. I need to sit down and watch them all. I did notice one specific omission from that particular video - and that was how to get Visual Studio to compile the module for you into a single .js file. It's as simple as clicking the `Combine JavaScript outputs into one file` but it took me half the afternoon to figure out how. I don't have large enough files to warrant an external loader so I wanted the IDE to compile down to one file. Maybe thats a new feature but I wish it had been in that video to save me hours :)

Comment: I realize that you don't use Visual Studio and maybe that's a new feature anyway now, but that checkbox is making my life a lot easier now I've found it

Comment: @Simon_Weaver Thanks :). FYI If you use that feature please be aware that you need a `_reference` file to manage the order in which the TypeScript files are combined. PS: `grunt-ts` can create that for you https://github.com/grunt-ts/grunt-ts#reference-file-generation